How to identify Current year earning row in Xero response
I am using calling https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/ endpoint to get the balance sheet report.  Now from the response I need to pick the "Net income" row which is called "Crrent year earnings" in Xero.
I am currently reading first cell of every row and checking if it's title property is "Current year earnings".  But this is a bad approach because if tomorrow Xero team changes the displayname then my code will break. Can someone tell me what will be the best way to identify Net income row in balance sheet

At the moment the display name will not change as the reports endpoint uses the V1 reports and this is deprecated in the front end of Xero.
Until the announcement of any replacement of the reports endpoint, your method will work. There are no current plans to change the reports endpoint and there would be at least 90 days notice of any changes when these are planned.
